# How to force Hibernate to look into second level cache

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, ehcache

I have a problem with retrieving data from Hibernate Second level cache.

The second level cache is working for sure.

When I call this

```
@QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true")})
List<T> findAll(Specification<T> spec);
```

the entities are saved in cache, and in next call it's retrieved from cache.
There are entities with ID 1,2,3,4....

But when I call

```
@QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true")})
T findOne(Specification<T> spec);
```

the entity which is already in second level cache it's not retrieved from this cache.

Is there a way to tell hibernate that he already has this entity in cache ?

note: when I call findAll the second level cachce has size of 44 entities, and after call findOne, the size is same, so the entity is for sure in the cache

Thank you.

Comment: query cache != second level cache. The query with the result is cached. Not the entities. It should still issue a query but in the end retrieve the value from the second level cache. But as stated query cache isn't second level cache.